# SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK при попытке отправить данные

Tags: php, curl, https

При попытке отправить данные через SSL:

```
$curl = curl_init();  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url); curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);// ждем ответа от страницы(либо false)
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);//отправка методом POST
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $text);//отправляем данные на url 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 200);// ждем ответ 200 секунд
$out = curl_exec($curl);
```

возникает ошибка

> *SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL* routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:*certificate
>   verify failed*

Пыталась исправить ее, перепробовав все решения, указанные [здесь](http://budiirawan.com/solution-error-60-ssl-certificate-problem-verify-ca-cert-ok/), а именно:

1. Вставить в php.ini `curl.cainfo=\your-path-to\cacert.pem`
2. Добавить в код `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "YOUR_PATH_TO/cacert.pem");`
3. Добавить в код `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);`

Однако первые два не дали никакого результата, а при использовании третьего ошибка ушла, но соединение вместо ответа возвращает false. URL и передаваемые данные верны.

Comment: Тут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400300/https-and-ssl3-get-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed-ca-is-ok ответы посмотрите.

Answer (score 1):

Причин, по которым первые два варианта не дали результата я вижу две:

1. По указанному пути нету файла с корневыми сертификатами или он не в формате PEM;
2. В данном файле нету корневого сертификата, который может подтвердить подлинность вашего сервера

Если у вас есть openssl, попробуйте выполнить

```
openssl s_client -connect имя_вашего_сервера:порт -CAfile файл_с_корневыми_сертификатами
```

Затем обратите внимание на строчки, начинающиеся с 'verify error', это вам подсказка что *действительно* не так. Проблема будет решена, если 'verify error' не будет появляться. (кстати выходить из openssl придется по `Ctrl+C`)

Comment: файл в формате pem, и находится он по указанному пути, так что дело скорее всего не в этом. Не могли бы Вы пояснить 2 пункт? если честно, то я просто скопировала текст из https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem и сохранила его с расширением pem, так можно было?

Comment: Да, можно. Однако не факт, что в этом файле есть нужный сертификат. `openssl s_client` в числе прочего укажет цифровой отпечаток сертификата, которым подписан сертификат сервера. В качестве решения можно зайти на нужный вам сайт брайзером, посмотреть в свойствах соединения корневой сертификат и сохранить его в формате pem. Потом указать его curl'у

Comment: зашла на нужный сайт, все сохранила, но ошибка все равно появляется

Comment: [Давайте переместимся в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36735/discussion-on-http-ru-stackoverflow-com-questions-501080)

Comment: извините, никак не получается в чате отправить сообщение(   версия curl 7.24.0